# LINQ if in where condition

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to know if it's possible to only take a where condition in LINQ if a checkbox is checked.

```
var y = from x in db.RandomTable
        where /*??if checkbox.Checked=true??*/x.RandomInteger == 0
        select x;
```

Comment: Yes, you just check for the checkbox being checked first and don't run the thing at all if it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var y = from x in db.RandomTable
    where !checkBox.Checked || x.RandomInteger == 0
    select x;
```

Answer (score 0):

To create clear code I would go into direction of syntax:

```
var q = db.RandomTable as IQueryable;
if (checkBox.Checked)
{
    q = q.Where(/* condition */);
}
var y = q.Select(/* whatever you want to select */);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it

```
IQueryable qry = db.RandomTable;

if (Checkbox.Checked) qry = qry.Where( x => x.RandomInteger == 0);

var result == qry.ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var checked = checkbox.Checked;

var y = from x in db.RandomTable
                where !checked || (checked && x.RandomInteger == 0)
                select x;
```